# Android linear layout overlapping

Tags: android, android-layout

Textview fills all the space and leaves no room for the other text view.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/cv_prof"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/cv_prof"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_other_user_chat"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sf_pro_display_light"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_theme"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_time_sent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sf_pro_display_light"
            android:text="@string/placeholder_time"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

How can i achieve this results?
Please help me

Result 1:

[image: Result 1]

Result 2:
[image: Result 2]

Answer (score 0):

You should add `layout_weight` element into child view of LinearLayout. Ex:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/cv_prof"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/cv_prof"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_other_user_chat"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sf_pro_display_light"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_theme"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_time_sent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sf_pro_display_light"
            android:text="@string/placeholder_time"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

set weight = 1 for 2 TextViews that mean width of them will be the same.

**Edit:**

If you want to use constrain layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_pdf"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_pdf"
        android:text="abcdjhfjdgfgfdgdfgfdgfdg gfdg hgjkdfhgj fdghjkfdhg hgjkfdh sdgdfg fgnjkdfgh fghfdhg fgjk"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_time_sent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageview" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_time_sent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10:00pm"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageview" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: this will make text views share the layout equally which i dont want

Comment: @Paul You can set different weight for each view. Or do you want it scale automatically depend on content of each view?

Comment: i want to scale it automatically

Comment: @Paul i think you should change to use constraint layout for this. Don't forget to set width = 0dp if you want views auto fill all screen.

Comment: `<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_content”
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 ….
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_time_sent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_time_sent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 ….
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_content”/>`
I tried this but it didnt work when content gets longer

Comment: @Paul see my edit. Hope it help